# Using Spark SQL to perform ETL on tens of gigabytes on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read this article [Using Spark SQL for ETL](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/) that describes how to use `spark sql` to perform ETL using `Hive` and `Spark SQL` but I have a different use case.

My data is stored in `mongodb` and it is approximatively 20 gigabytes. I know that `spark` is good for big data ( terabytes, petabytes) so I am wondering how it would perform on tens of gigabytes at a time using a basic standalone cluster, a single node ( 8 cores , 128 GB ram) or a master and a slave?

I can perform ETL using `mongo`'s aggregation framework and a programming language but I want to build a scalable solution. Also the aggregation framework is kind of limited when you want to run a complex query so you have to do part of the job programatically